# Display data thanks id in URL on other page React

Tags: reactjs, api, react-router-dom

I am training on React and I would like to click on the product title to display a detail page of this product. So I used react-router-dom to simulate multiple pages. I have data from a fake API that I displayed in a table and I would like to retrieve it on another page so for that I retrieve the ID of the data and I retrieved this id in the page "productsDetails" but I can't retrieve the other data like title, description ...

Thank you in advance for your explanations

[Photo project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6otM.png)

App

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './css/App.css';
import './css/Products.css'
import Navigation from './Components/Navigation';
import Products from './Components/Products';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch,} from 'react-router-dom';
import ProductsDetails from './Components/ProductsDetails1';


export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App"> 
      <Router>
        <Navigation />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Products} />
          <Route path="/products-details/:id" component={ProductsDetails} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Products

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../css/Products.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import './ProductsDetails1'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

export default class Products extends Component {
    state = {
        productsData: []
      }
      componentDidMount = () => {
        axios.get('https://fakestoreapi.com/products?limit=7')
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res.data)
          this.setState ({
            productsData: res.data
          })
        })
      }
    render() {
        const listsProducts = this.state.productsData.map(listProduct => {
            return <tbody className="products__body">
                    <tr>
                        <td> <Link to={"/products-details/"+listProduct.id}>{listProduct.title}</Link></td>
                        <td>{listProduct.category}</td>
                        <td>{listProduct.price}</td>
                        <td>{Math.round((listProduct.price + listProduct.price * 0.2)*100) /100}</td>
                    </tr> 
              </tbody>
          })
        return (
            <main className="products">
                <h1 className="products__title">Products management</h1>
                <table cellSpacing="0">
                <thead className="products__head">
                    <tr>
                    <th className="table--title">Product name</th>
                    <th className="table--title">Category</th>
                    <th className="table--title">Price</th>
                    <th className="table--title">Price (including VAT)</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                  {listsProducts}
                </table>
            </main>
        )
    }
}
```

ProductsDetails

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import '../css/ProductsDetails.css'

export default class ProductsDetails extends Component {
    state = {
        id: this.props.match.params.id,

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="products__details">
                {this.state.id}
            </div>
        )
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way for now would be to send the `listProduct` in route state to the `ProductsDetails` page.

In products when computing the link, also pass the product:

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/products-details/" + listProduct.id,
    state: {
      listProduct
    }
  }}
>
```

Update `ProductDetails` to access the route state:

```
class ProductsDetails extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      location: {
        state: { listProduct }
      },
      match: {
        params: { id }
      }
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="products__details">
        {id}
        <div>{listProduct.description}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit display-data-thanks-id-in-url-on-other-page-react]

If/when your app/state grows in size and complexity you will want to implementing better state management by [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) or by using a [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), or eventually Redux.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I updated my code as you said but when I click on one of the product link it displays an error: 
"Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. "

Comment: @RitalCharmant What and where are you render an object? Are you trying to render the entire `listProduct` directly in the `ProductsDetails` component?

Comment: It's okay I understood my mistake, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @RitalCharmant Great! Cheers and good luck.